# Can I add a class to all form buttons in the Silverstripe framework?

Tags: php, zurb-foundation, silverstripe

We're wanting to do some fast prototyping using Zurb Foundation on Silverstripe. This is the Silverstripe theme for Foundation: http://silverstripe-foundation.com/kitchen-sink/

The issue is the class "button" has to be applied to form input fields for them to inherit the Foundation styling. Otherwise the browser default is used, which looks bad. Other form fields inherit the correct style.

There's a method addExtraClass in FormField: http://api.silverstripe.org/3.1/source-class-FormField.html#300-314

How would I apply this to all form buttons generated by the framework?

Comment: There is a `onBeforeRender` hook on `FormField`. I wonder if you could  use it in a `DataExtension` checking if $this->owner is a `FormAction` and adding extra class if so?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The developers of this theme [recommend](https://github.com/ryanwachtl/silverstripe-foundation-theme#recommended) you to use the [SilverStripe ZURB Foundation Forms Module](https://github.com/ryanwachtl/silverstripe-foundation-forms). This will add all the classes needed by the theme styling for all the form elements automatically.

Comment: Thanks - I'd missed that.